# dataTransform in Deepstream.io gives 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input' in the console

Tags: javascript, sockets, deepstream.io

I'm trying to manipulate the data that is sent back to the client via Deepstream with the new `dataTransforms` API, however, I always get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` in the console. It might be that it takes too long to make the database lookup for Deepstream but I'm not quite sure.

My relevant code is:

```
DSServer.set('dataTransforms', [
  {
    topic: DSServer.constants.TOPIC.RECORD,
    action: DSServer.constants.ACTIONS.READ,
    transform: transformRecord
  }
]);

var transformRecord = function (data, metadata) {
  if (metadata.recordName.split('/')[0] === 'team') {
    var new_member_info = [];
    var i = 0;

    _.forEach(data.members, function (members) {
      r.table('user').get(members.user_id).run()
        .then(function (doc) {
          if (doc !== null) {
            new_member_info.push({
              user_id: members.user_id,
              display_name: doc._d.display_name,
              username: doc._d.username
            });

            i += 1;

            if (i === data.members.length) {
              data.members = new_member_info;
              return data;
            }
          }
        })
        .error(function (err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
    });
  } else {
    return data;
  }
};
```

Whenever there is READ from a RECORD it will check if it's a read from the team record. If it is a read from the team-record it will fetch all members that are a part of that team and add it to members: {}.

When it has iterated over all members and added the information about them it will return the new data.

So, any idea what might be wrong?

Am I understanding the `dataTransforms` wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons, all data-transforms are expected to return a result synchronously.

```
r.table('user').get(members.user_id).run()
        .then(...
```

however runs asynchronously and returns its value to the function used in `then`, rather than the dataTransform function. It's also crucial to always return the data, whether transformations were applied or not.

If I understand it correctly, your usecase is to load information for a number of users from a RethinkDb server. Might I recommend either using a [list](http://deepstream.io/docs/list.html) of recordnames for this usecase or build a [data provider](http://deepstream.io/tutorials/data-provider.html) to interact with RethinkDb.

Comment: Will try this sometime =)

However, we decided to go another route for this particular problem. Thanks for the reply!